# Exchange SOAP Request : Property LastModifiedTime

Tags: soap, request, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I would like to retrieve the property LastModifiedTime of an appointement and/or a meeting.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa564765(v=exchg.150).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa564765%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx)

I do my SOAP request with GetItem to retrieve the appointment and his properties :

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn439786(v=exchg.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn439786%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)

(in the BaseShape I ask all of his properties)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <ns0:Body>
      <m:GetItem xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"        xmlns:schema="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <m:ItemShape>
         <t:BaseShape>AllProperties</t:BaseShape>
      </m:ItemShape>
      <m:ItemIds>
         <t:ItemId Id="AAAcAEFkbWluaXN0cmF0b3JAZWV6ZWUtaXQubG9jYWwARgAAAAAA4lfWZk1Jn0GdeuXZ7dD1wQcAe2rqVPFj70qxiOX5GP9RagAAAAAADwAAe2rqVPFj70qxiOX5GP9RagAABT20UgAA" />
      </m:ItemIds>
      </m:GetItem>
   </ns0:Body>
</ns0:Envelope>
```

And the response is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Header>
      <h:ServerVersionInfo xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" MajorVersion="15" MinorVersion="0" MajorBuildNumber="516" MinorBuildNumber="29" />
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <m:GetItemResponse xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
         <m:ResponseMessages>
            <m:GetItemResponseMessage ResponseClass="Success">
               <m:ResponseCode>NoError</m:ResponseCode>
               <m:Items>
                 <t:CalendarItem>
                    <t:ItemId Id="AAAcAEFkbWluaXN0cmF0b3JAZWV6ZWUtaXQubG9jYWwARgAAAAAA4lfWZk1Jn0GdeuXZ7dD1wQcAe2rqVPFj70qxiOX5GP9RagAAAAAADwAAe2rqVPFj70qxiOX5GP9RagAABT20UgAA" ChangeKey="DwAAABYAAAB7aupU8WPvSrGI5fkY/1FqAAAFPbiG" />
                    <t:ParentFolderId Id="AQAcAEFkbWluaXN0cmF0b3JAZWUAemVlAC1pdC5sb2NhbAAuAAAD4lfWZk1Jn0GdeuXZ7dD1wQEAe2rqVPFj70qxiOX5GP9RagAAAw8AAAA=" ChangeKey="AQAAAA==" />
                    <t:ItemClass>IPM.Appointment</t:ItemClass>
                    <t:Subject>my_appointment</t:Subject>
                    <t:Sensitivity>Normal</t:Sensitivity>
                    <t:Body BodyType="Text" />
                    <t:DateTimeReceived>2014-05-06T13:04:36Z</t:DateTimeReceived>
                    <t:Size>3025</t:Size>
                    <t:Importance>Normal</t:Importance>
                    <t:IsSubmitted>false</t:IsSubmitted>
                    <t:IsDraft>false</t:IsDraft>
                    <t:IsFromMe>false</t:IsFromMe>
                    <t:IsResend>false</t:IsResend>
                    <t:IsUnmodified>false</t:IsUnmodified>
                    <t:DateTimeSent>2014-05-06T13:04:36Z</t:DateTimeSent>
                    <t:DateTimeCreated>2014-05-06T13:04:36Z</t:DateTimeCreated>
                    <t:ResponseObjects>
                       <t:CancelCalendarItem />
                       <t:ForwardItem />
                    </t:ResponseObjects>
                    <t:ReminderDueBy>2014-05-05T22:00:00Z</t:ReminderDueBy>
                    <t:ReminderIsSet>true</t:ReminderIsSet>
                    <t:ReminderMinutesBeforeStart>15</t:ReminderMinutesBeforeStart>
                    <t:DisplayCc />
                    <t:DisplayTo />
                    <t:HasAttachments>false</t:HasAttachments>
                    <t:Culture>en-US</t:Culture>
                    <t:Start>2014-05-05T22:00:00Z</t:Start>
                    <t:End>2014-05-06T22:00:00Z</t:End>
                    <t:IsAllDayEvent>true</t:IsAllDayEvent>
                    <t:LegacyFreeBusyStatus>Busy</t:LegacyFreeBusyStatus>
                    <t:Location />
                    <t:IsMeeting>true</t:IsMeeting>
                    <t:IsCancelled>false</t:IsCancelled>
                    <t:IsRecurring>false</t:IsRecurring>
                    <t:MeetingRequestWasSent>false</t:MeetingRequestWasSent>
                    <t:IsResponseRequested>true</t:IsResponseRequested>
                    <t:CalendarItemType>Single</t:CalendarItemType>
                    <t:MyResponseType>Organizer</t:MyResponseType>
                    <t:Organizer>
                       <t:Mailbox>
                          <t:Name>Administrator</t:Name>
                          <t:EmailAddress>Administrator@domain.local</t:EmailAddress>
                          <t:RoutingType>SMTP</t:RoutingType>
                       </t:Mailbox>
                    </t:Organizer>
                    <t:Duration>P1D</t:Duration>
                    <t:TimeZone>(UTC+01:00) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris</t:TimeZone>
                    <t:AppointmentSequenceNumber>0</t:AppointmentSequenceNumber>
                    <t:AppointmentState>1</t:AppointmentState>
                 </t:CalendarItem>
              </m:Items>
           </m:GetItemResponseMessage>
        </m:ResponseMessages>
     </m:GetItemResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

So, in the reply from my server, I don't have the property LastModifiedTime that I want.

How can I retrieve this property "LastModifiedTime"?

Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

LastModifiedTime is one of the first class properties returned on a CalendarItem, so I don't know why you're not getting it. I retrieved a calendar item with your same request:

```
<m:ItemShape>
    <t:BaseShape>AllProperties</t:BaseShape>
</m:ItemShape>
```

and I got the LastModifiedTime back:

```
<t:LastModifiedTime>2014-05-16T19:28:16Z</t:LastModifiedTime>
```

To request LastModifiedTime specifically, you can change your request to include the following:

```
    <m:ItemShape>
      <t:BaseShape>AllProperties</t:BaseShape>
      <t:AdditionalProperties>
        <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:LastModifiedTime" />
      </t:AdditionalProperties>
    </m:ItemShape>
```